# Python linked list TypeError: 'linked_list' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, for-loop, linked-list, iterable

i have created a linked list but when i tried to use for loop to browse thru the linked list it says TypeError: 'linked_list' object is not iterable

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLNaS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwaz6.png)

My Linked list code below:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
    
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node()

    def append(self,data):
        new_node = node(data)
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next!=None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = new_node

    def length(self):
        cur = self.head
        total = 0
        while cur.next!=None:
            total+=1
            cur = cur.next
        return total

    def display(self):
        elems = []
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next!=None:
            cur_node=cur_node.next
            elems.append(cur_node.data)
        print(elems)

    def get(self,index):
        if index>=self.length():
            print("Error. Index out of range!")
            return None
        cur_idx=0
        cur_node=self.head
        while True:
            cur_node=cur_node.next
            if cur_idx==index:  return cur_node.data
            cur_idx+=1

    def erase(self,index):
        if index   >=self.length():
            print("Error. Index out of range!")
            return
        cur_idx=0
        cur_node=self.head
        while True:
            last_node = cur_node
            cur_node = cur_node.next
            if cur_idx==index:
                last_node.next = cur_node.next
                return
            cur_idx+=1

    def listprint(self):
        printval = self.head
        while printval is not None:
            print(printval.data)
            printval = printval.next
            #print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  If you feel the need to obfuscate the paths, just use dummy path names.  The main issue is the traceback.

Comment: What did you expect that to do?  If you want your class to be iterable, then you have to make it one, by implementing the `__iter__` and `__next__` special methods.

Comment: You need to also include how you defined ```dvdlist```, though assuming you have something along the lines of ```dvdlist = linked_list()```; then, as @TimRoberts mentioned, you need to implement those two required methods.

Comment: Don't provide code as images!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create iterable object, you must implement the `__iter__()` method
Python's iteration protocol requires `__iter__()` to return a special iterator object, which must implement the `__next__()` method and use the `StopIteration` exception to inform the iteration of completion.
However, generator are simpler, i add `loop()` in class `linked_list`

```
class linked_list:

    def loop(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next:
            yield cur_node.next.data
            cur_node = cur_node.next

a = linked_list()
a.append("how")
a.append("are")
a.append("you")

for i in a.loop():
    print(i)
```

Output

```
how
are
you
```

With generator, it's easy to implement `__iter__()`

```
class linked_list:

    def loop(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next:
            yield cur_node.next.data
            cur_node = cur_node.next

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.loop())


for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Output

```
how
are
you
```

Answer (score -2):

[image]
You already finished the right function in your class. You should use the function in the class

As for traverse the whole link, you should use

```
cur=dvdlist.head
while cur!=None:
    do_something()
    cur=cur.next
```